# "complex" grouping and sorting with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a problem to which I can't seem to find a solution.

I want to achieve the following:
* i have a list of tasks, each with an owner and a due date
* i want to display a list of all tasks grouped by owner
* i want to sort the owners based on the due dates: e.g. The owner with the lowest due date first, followed by the owner with the second lowest, etc

To ilustrate, this would be a result i am looking for:

Harry
- task 1, due date 1
- task 3, due date 4
Ben
- task 2, due date 2
Carol
- task 4, due date 3

I am using sunspot to search and filter results, so ideally i would like to use sunspot to do this. I've been trying to get the results with facets and ordering but haven't gotten this result to work yet(i can group by owners, or order by due date just not both).

Any help would be appreciated.

Erwin

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the [Result Grouping/Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) feature of solr.

Unfortunately, this is a fairly new feature in solr, and [isn't yet supported in sunspot](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot/browse_thread/thread/e1449b67b40d9f6d/c4d8f265623cfef1?lnk=gst&q=result%20grouping#c4d8f265623cfef1) (as of 1.3.0).  However, it is under active development and explicitly listed as a feature for a "future release".  This might be soon-ish, as a [pull request for this feature was just submitted a couple days ago](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/136).

If you haven't found a workaround, you could grab the code from that pull request and see if it does what you need it to do....always fun to walk on the bleeding edge, right? :)

**UPDATE**: Support for field grouping was just merged in to the master branch of sunspot.  [Check it out](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). The readme for sunspot has been updated with examples of how to do exactly what you're trying to do.